# OneNote and c# code to execute a VBA macro

Tags: c#, vba, add-in, onenote

My goal is to make a free add-in for OneNote to help child that have computer at school.
Here is the ribbon I've done for my daughter in Word:
[image]
<sub>(source: [ellip6.com](http://pro.ellip6.com/SebastienForum/WordRibbon.jpg))</sub>

Actually I've modify the OneNote Ribbon to add buttons now I need to add some code to execute some simple function.

- Select red pen
- Underline Selected text
- Add border to selected text
- Modify style.

Once I've found how to make one command , it will be easy to do the rest.

Comment: OneNote does not have built-in macro scripting or VBA functionality, though it does have a C# API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575420.aspx

Comment: I've seen the API , but no example how to use it. Is there a website that explain how Onenote works? to understand the structure of the pages. Thks

Comment: To be fair, the OneNote API is meant for the "online" OneNote service. The actual desktop Office OneNote application doesn't have an extensibility system.

Comment: So you mean that it is impossible to make such code for OneNote ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the OneNote page are XML file is it possible to inject some text in the page with a button. 
for example : 
rouge => it make rouge in red.

Thks